# How to achieve "instagram camera" scrolling in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to achieve this effect in flutter using a ScrollView inside a PageView:

https://ibb.co/dMd3TZL

But when I scroll to the second page I get stuck and I can't go back anymore.

Sample code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Demo"),
            ),
            body: PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children:[
                Container(color: Colors.red),
                ListView(
                  children:[
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow, height:300),
                    Container(color: Colors.green, height:300),
                  ]
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

How can I send onDrag event to the PageView when the ScrollView has reached the end?

Answer (score 0):

listview will not work with pageviewer, so use wrap Widget instead of listview, like this,

```
PageView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children:[
      Container(color: Colors.red),
      Wrap(
          children:[
            Container(color: Colors.yellow, height:300),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height:300),
          ]
      )

    ],
  ),
```

Comment: But now if I have multiple Container in Wrap I can't scroll them all